# How to pass data to scrapinghub?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm trying to run a scrapy spider on scrapinghub, and I want to pass in some data. I'm using their API to run the spider:

http://doc.scrapinghub.com/api/jobs.html#jobs-run-json

They have an option for `job_settings`, which seems relevant, but I can't figure out how to access the `job_settings` data in my `Spider` class. What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `job_settings` shall be merged directly into the [Scrapy settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html), with a higher precedence (of `40`, IIRC).

The Scrapy settings could be accessed via a `.settings` attribute of a spider instance, e.g. you could use `self.settings` if `self` is a `scrapy.Spider` instance.